# Using clusters with an association table

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I am pretty new to databases and I am trying to learn how to use clusters in Oracle. Let's say we have this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table1, Table2, Table3
WHERE  Table1.a = Table3.a
AND    Table2.a = Table3.b
```

How do I create a HASH CLUSTER to optimize this query? Since Table3 is a join table, how can we create the cluster?

Because if I do this:

```
CREATE CLUSTER Cluster (a INTEGER)
SIZE 1000 HASHKEYS 10000;
```

Then when I create Table3 I can only choose one column for the cluster.

Please enlighten me.

Comment: There's no specific reason to use a Cluster. I haven't seen any genuine use case for them. If you are learning about them it's fine but we rarely use that in real time. If it's the performance impact due to joins is what you are concerned in your query, I would suggest a Materialised view. Another important point: Use the explicit `JOIN ON` syntax rather than the outdated comma( as in `t1,t2,t3` ) syntax for joins.

Comment: Do the tables share a common key? That is what clusters are for. Note that clusters have some limitations around partitioning, and also that nobody has used one for twenty years.

Comment: Yes, I am currently learning them in my database class. Table1 and Table3 have a common key and Table2 and Table3 have another common key. Table3 is considered a join table in that case. Thanks for letting me know that I won't have to use this in the future, but I currently need to find the best way to optimize this with HASH CLUSTERS or INDEX CLUSTERS and I thought HASH CLUSTERS were the best way to do it but I just don't know how.